# Multiple words check

Tags: regex

I am trying to check for multiple words with regex but I couldn't.

```
@"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s].{1,35}"
```

"foo" should fail

"foo " should fail

"foo boo" should success

"foo boo moo" should success

Comment: Regex is a bad choice when the task is simple. Simple `String.Split` should do the trick.

Comment: Maybe `@"^\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,34}$"`?

Comment: would `str.Split(' ').Length > 1` not work?...

Comment: I need regex, can't use c# code regarding to architecture

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew looks promising, trying to test.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew can you make it answer so I can accept it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely, if you can use the code, you just need to check if splitting with a whitespace results in more chunks than 1 (splitting without empty elements).

> I need regex, can't use c# code regarding to architecture

If a regex is necessary to match any string that can have 2 to 35 space-separated words consisting of "word" chars (that is, letters, digits or underscores) you may use

```
@"^\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,34}$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jN2zE4/1)

If you only need to allow letters or digits, subtract the underscore from `\w`:

```
@"^[\w-[_]]+(?:\s+[\w-[_]]+){1,34}$"
   ^^^^^^^^
```

Also, note that `[\w-[_]]` = `[^\W_]` (it is a bit shorter). And  if you only need to allow 1 single whitespace between words, remove the `+` after `\s`.

```
@"^[\w-[_]]+(?:\s[\w-[_]]+){1,34}$"
                ^^
```

Comment: turns out I need to allow special characters aswell like "." or "&" ect. I am using this one @"^\w+(?:\s+\w+){1,34}$"

Comment: Where do you need to match them? If anywhere, use `@"^[-&.\w]+(?:\s+[-&.\w]+){1,34}$"`

Comment: Wiktor you are such a big help, but I need to accept all characters I guess, like russian characters fench characters even maybe japanese/chinese charaters too. any solution for that?

Comment: What is the language?

Comment: language is c# .net

Comment: sorry, It should be javascript. <input pattern="^[-&amp;.&amp;()@:;>&lt;,.\/’#\w]+(?:\s+[-&amp;.\w]+){1,34}$">

Comment: Use XRegExp `\pL`.

Comment: alternative is to add every characters I want to use? like this [-çğşéяшы.&()@:;><,.\/’#\w]

Comment: Yes if the number of alphabets/scripts is limited and known beforehand.

Comment: thank you very much, we will use simple/easy way. just check for space character and minimum 3 characters. It could fail but Its acceptable.